Replace greek letters in newtx with cm version
Hi all,
I am currently procrastinating setting up and optimizing my font selection in my standard template. I am using the newtx package (by Michael Sharpe) with the cochineal option and scaled=1.06 in combination with the mathalpha package to select calligraphic and blackboard fonts according to my liking (cal=cm and bb=ams).
While I am quite happy with this setup, I do not like the greek symbols in math mode.
I would like to replace the greek mathematics symbols with the default ones from cm, however can't figure out how to do this. I have tried to use the \DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\rmdefault}{cm} command, but that does not take any effect (supposedly due to the routines running behind newtx?).
Now, after spending more hours than I am willing to admit in trying to find a solution to this (and failed) I would be more than happy if any of you can help me out.
[And yes, I am bound to using pdflatex (otherwise this would be an easy fix using the powerful font assignment possibilities for xelatex and luatex).]
Thanks a lot already for your help!

Minimal Working Example:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % spell out all text encodings used
\usepackage[
    p,
    scaled=1.06,  % because I fool myself I could see the difference
    varvw,  % variants for v and w to distingish from \nu and \omega 
    cochineal,  %  main font choice
    ]{newtx}  % amsmath is loaded in here
\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\rmdefault}{cm}  % this line seems not to take any effect
\usepackage{dsfont}  % for identity matrix 
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=boondoxo,bb=ams]{mathalpha} 

\newcommand{\abc}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\title{My Minimal Working Example}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1] % some text

\abc % capitals alphabet

\MakeLowercase{\abc} % lower case alphabet

\begin{align*} % some greek symbols
    \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \psi, \phi, \theta, \omega, \epsilon, \delta, \rho, \varepsilon, \vartheta, \\%\updelta\\ 
    \Gamma,  \Psi, \Phi, \Theta, \Omega, \Delta, %\upDelta, \upOmega, \upGamma
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}  % math numbers and letters
    1234567890\\ 
    \abc\\ 
    \MakeLowercase{\abc}
\end{align*}

% compare to textit letters
\textit{\abc \\ 
\MakeLowercase{\abc}}

\begin{align*} % math alphabets
    \mathcal{\abc}\\
    \mathscr{\abc}\\ 
    \mathbb{\abc}\\
    \mathds{1}\\
    \mathtt{\abc}\\ 
    \mathtt{\MakeLowercase{\abc}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*} % matrix example
    M = 
    \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 &  1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*} % math example
    \sum_{n=3}^{M- \frac{\nu}{\xi}} \frac{M+ \frac{a}{b}}{1-\frac{c}{d}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}

(While only the line with greek letters is pedantically speaking required for the above issue I still left the other lines in the MWE since they indicate the constraints, which should not be broken).

The uppercase upright Greek letters (as well as the lowercase italic ones) are taken from Cochineal. Why would you want to replace them taking glyphs from a font whose design obviously clashes with Cochineal's?

Thanks for your opinion. I see it as this: In a bigger picture my question asks for a method to replace the greek letters with those of some (any) other font (and which I prefer visually). I do not like the greek letters of most old style fonts while I do prefer the roman letters of those fonts. And CMR has in my (opinionated) opinion the nicest greek letter. Additionally, not having a method to choose and change I don't yet have a clear opinion of whether I find those letters to match or clash.

After applying your solution from below and incorporating the remaining greek letters I settled to the libertinus option of newtx combined with the MLModern version of the greek math letters (which is slightly heavier than the cm version). And I find this design much better (ie cleaner) than the original greek math letters and which fits (due to the heavier) nicely with the main font.

It's not difficult to do it, but I wouldn't.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % spell out all text encodings used
\usepackage[
    p,
    scaled=1.06,  % because I fool myself I could see the difference
    varvw,  % variants for v and w to distingish from \nu and \omega 
    cochineal,  %  main font choice
    ]{newtx}  % amsmath is loaded in here
\usepackage{dsfont}  % for identity matrix 
\usepackage[cal=cm,scr=boondoxo,bb=ams]{mathalpha} 

\newcommand{\abc}{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_map_inline:nn { Gamma,Delta,Theta,Lambda,Xi,Pi,Sigma,Upsilon,Phi,Psi,Omega}
 {
  \cs_set_eq:cc { o#1 } { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmupright}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"00}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"01}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"02}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"03}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"04}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"05}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"06}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"07}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"08}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"09}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{cmupright}{"0A}




\title{My Minimal Working Example}



\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{First Section}

\lipsum[1] % some text

\abc % capitals alphabet

\MakeLowercase{\abc} % lower case alphabet

{\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont abgdezhfjywABGDEZHFJYW}

{\fontencoding{LGR}\itshape abgdezhfjywABGDEZHFJYW}

\begin{align*} % some greek symbols
& \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \psi, \phi, \theta, \omega, \epsilon, 
  \delta, \rho, \varepsilon, \vartheta, \\ 
& \Gamma,  \Psi, \Phi, \Theta, \Omega, \Delta, \\
& \oGamma,  \oPsi, \oPhi, \oTheta, \oOmega, \oDelta
\end{align*}

\end{document}

The \o<Name> commands are just for comparing the outputs.


Thanks for the answer @egreg! This helps a lot! Do I see it right that there is no generic way to exchange the whole greek alphabet, but that I need to iterate through each greek letter? Also, which document is the right one to look up which letter has which code (i.e. the entry of the last field in the \DeclareMathSymbol command)?

@uzer.name The Greek letters in math have specific math codes and there's no “global list” for them. You can check fontmath.ltx for the standard math codes. Always remember that “if something is difficult to do with LaTeX, then it's probably wrong”.

While probably true, the art is to understand whether its truly difficult or whether I (from my incomplete knowledge) simply don't know the simple solution . Thanks for the help!
